# WPF DataGrd not refreshing properly because of another thread

Tags: wpf, multithreading, datagrid

I am developing a WPF application which is bind to a DataGrid as given below:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource tradeViewModel},
                                Path=Result}"
```

Where the Path pointing to Result property in view model which inturn calls `TradePriceChanger.GetTrades()`

The TradePriceChanger.GetTrades method return sList of Trade as given below:

```
public static class TradePriceChanger
{
    static List<Trade> tradeList = new List<Trade>();
    static int TradeCounter = 1;
    static ManualResetEvent manualReset = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public static IEnumerable<Trade> GetTrades()
    {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(One));
        t1.Start();

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Two));
        t2.Start();

        manualReset.WaitOne();

        return tradeList;
    }


    public static void One()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            tradeList.Add(new Trade ( "One" + i,  i ));
        }
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref TradeCounter);
        if (TradeCounter == 0)
            manualReset.Set();
    }

    public static void Two()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            tradeList.Add(new Trade("Two" + i, i));
        }
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref TradeCounter);
        if (TradeCounter == 0)
            manualReset.Set();
    }
}
```

And the Trade class has a timer which updates its price to a random value after every 1sec.

```
public class Trade:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    private double _price;

    public Trade(string name, double price)
    {
        _name = name;
        _price = price;

        TimerCallback callback = new TimerCallback(ChangePrice);
        Timer timer = new Timer(callback, this, 0, 1000);
    }

    private static void ChangePrice(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Trade)
        {
            Trade trade = obj as Trade;
            trade.Price = trade.Price + ( new Random().Next(-1,2) * (new Random().NextDouble()));
        }
    }

    public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }
    public double Price
    {
        get
        {
            return _price;
        }
        set
        {
            _price = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Price"));
            }
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion
}
```

Now the problem is the values in the grid are refreshing properly When I run only thread t1 in the TradePriceChanger.GetTrades(). But, If I run both, no refresh is happening on UI.

Am I missing something here.

Please let me know.

Thanks,
Mahesh

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're only waiting for one thread by using '`manualReset.WaitOne();`', but if you want both threads to have the time to execute,  you should use `WaitAll();` Else one thread could finish and the function would exit as the wait would have been satisfied.

It also seems you're adding to your tradelist without any thread synchronization, so both threads can write to this list and cause inconsistent state in your list

Comment: Was Mahesh intending to change 
static int TradeCounter = 1; 
to 
static int TradeCounter = 2;  ??